# Unresolved reference: RoomDatabase

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am trying to get Room set-up in my application  (following the documentation). Everything is compiling fine, except my `Database` class. The `RoomDatabase` class is not found. It is probably worth noting that I am using a Jetpack Compose Desktop app, not on Android.

```
import androidx.room.*

@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String?
)


@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND " +
            "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    fun findByName(first: String, last: String): User

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg users: User)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: User)
}

@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.10'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

}
```

Comment: we would need to see your code to diagnose the problem

Comment: I just copied and pasted from https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: it's hard to tell because there maybe a small error like an  import or something, i'm not gonna know how to compare what the documentation is saying and your code if I can't see it

Comment: OK I added the code to my question

Comment: Could you also post your gradle file?

Comment: Are the Dao, Entity, and Databases in their own class?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: the code you pasted in the first example, is that all within one file? Or are they seperated

Comment: all within one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work adding

```
id 'com.stepango.aar2jar' version "0.6"
```

to my `plugins` block. However, after adding the database initialization code to my main function, the code would no longer compile because the android `Context` class is required for DB initialization.

Comment: What did you end up using instead of Room?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that everything is in one file. You need to create a User.kt file:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String?
)
```

Then, a UserDao kotlin file:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND " +
           "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    fun findByName(first: String, last: String): User

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg users: User)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: User)
}
```

Then an app database kotlin file:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

My suggestion, would be to follow [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0). It will teach you the basics and walk you through a full fledge app. Good luck :)

Comment: You created each seperate class like I suggested? Did you follow the tutorial??

Comment: yes. I have already followed that tutorial. This is running in a Jetpack Compose desktop app, not on android. I believe that the problem is standard Gradle projects cannot depend on AAR files, while android gradle projects can.